# Excel: The Name of a Named Column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I use named Excel columns to simplify formulas. I would like to have the top cell of each such column serve as the column's title by displaying the column's name. How to I get the string?

Edit: @Andreas asked how naming columns simplify formulas. Giving variables meaningful names is one of the basic tenets of programming. Here is an example: Using "Relevant" or "LeftParentPos" are much more meaningful that A2 or B2.

Edit: @Terry  The name is just an alias - Excel doesn't change the title of the column. In the example, I can name column A as "Section" and referring to "Section" in formulas would be translated to "column A, same row as the cell containing the formula", but the user still sees "A" and not "Section". So, for readability I want to add a title row containing, for each column, the column's name.

[image]

Comment: you want to use a macro? or you want a formula to put in the cell?

Comment: Format your data as a Table?

Comment: Named columns? You mean you have renamed `A` to something else, to simplify? Really? I can't see how that simplifies it. Please clarify your question some more

Comment: so what exactly you do you want to achieve? Do you want to know how to give a name to a column? How to quickly name multiple columns by the column header? or something else?

Comment: What about using a table? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/overview-of-excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c You can use column names then in the formulas.

Comment: https://www.excel-university.com/indirectly-refer-to-table-columns/

Comment: Check out the INDIRECT function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use a table to accomplish what you are looking to do.  I agree that using more meaningful names makes reading the formulas (code) easier.

Format your data as a table and use the table headers.  When you create the formula, you will get the [@Table Header] instead of R1C1 variables (A1).

---

If you insist on not using a table (I would in this situation), you can create named columns by using dynamic named ranges.  Make sure the references are relative instead of absolute.

Highlight the row you want to first use.  That is the row you will place in the formula.  In the picture below, row 3 was highlighted.  So the dynamic named formula is `=Sheet1!$D3`.  Please notice the relative row.

[image]